# import gammu class - getting error no module named

Tags: python, gammu

I just want to get status from gammu

```
import gammu.smsd
smsd = gammu.smsd.SMSD('/etc/gammu-smsdrc')
print smsd.GetStatus()
```

I saved code to /home/pi/mypython.py
and ran it from terminal

```
sudo pyhton /home/pi/mypython.py
```

I'm getting an error

```
ImportError : No module named gammu.smsd
```

My target is getting Gammu Status, then if gammu status is stopped I will start it automaticly from other python code.

I was trying:

1. service gammu-smsd status
   **Result:** No help - just shown usage of gammu-smsd
2. service --status-all
   **Result:** I'm getting [?] gammu-smsd < unknown is started or stopped
   '
   Whats wrong with my code? Is there any step I need to do?

Comment: You made a good start on the diagnosis.  Have you tried some incremental imports to diagnose what stage is failing?  For instance ///import gammu /// from gammu import smsd///  These may help narrow the problem.

Comment: i was add on top line import gammu \n from gammu import smsd, still get no module named gammu

Comment: Which indicates that the problem is access to gammu.py, rather than smsd within that package.  Is gammu.py in your site-packages directory?  If not, where is it?  Is *that* directory in your Python search path?

Comment: i beginner on python, gammu an Raspberry, i dont understand what is Pyhton search path. i only can explain what in my Raspi right now. i was install gammu using sudo apt-get install gammu and sudo apt-get install gammu-smsd. file confiq of smsd is on /etc/gammu-smsdrc. status right now, gammu running well, connected to my modem. the file mypython.py i put on /home/pi. when i run it, i get that error

Comment: First of all, this is an installation problem, not a problem with any of the languages.  If you don't know what a "path variable" is on your system, you will need to look up a tutorial for this; I believe that it's beyond the scope of SO.  If you're doing this for a school project or something at work, there should be someone in your support staff there who can walk you through the basic parts of checking an installation for whatever operating system and software stack you're using.

Answer (score 0):

The [python bindings](http://wammu.eu/python-gammu/) are separate package, so you need to install it separately even if you already have Gammu installed.